# Chang size of points depending on one column with ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am looking for ways to plot the points depending on the value of a column, so some points would be bigger than the others. I am able to do it in ggvis as shown below but the difference between the sizes are not significant enough.

I am trying to reproduce this plot in ggvis.
https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&ctype=b&strail=false&nselm=s&met_x=sp_dyn_le00_in&scale_x=lin&ind_x=false&met_y=sp_dyn_tfrt_in&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&dimp_c=country:region&ifdim=country&iconSize=0.5&uniSize=0.035

```
  server <- function(input, output) {
  sub_df <- reactive({df[df$Year == input$year & df$Region %in% input$regions, ]})


  hover <- function(x) {
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    row <- df[df$Life == x$Life & df$Fertility == x$Fertility & !is.na(df$Life) & !is.na(df$Fertility), ]
    paste0(row$Country)
  }

  sub_df %>% 
    ggvis(x = ~Life, y = ~Fertility, fill = ~factor(Region), size = ~Population) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    add_axis("x", title = "Life Expectancy") %>%
    add_axis("y", title = "Fertility Rate") %>%
    add_legend("fill", title="Region", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 150))) %>%
    add_legend("size", title="Population", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 50))) %>%
    add_tooltip(hover, "hover") %>%
    scale_numeric("x", domain = c(limits$lifemin, limits$lifemax), nice = F) %>%
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(limits$fertilitymin, limits$fertilitymax), nice = F) %>%
    set_options(duration=0) %>%
    bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")

}
```

My plot looks like this:

[image]

Data can be found at:
http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.1564.TO.ZS?view=map

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please show the code you're using. Also add a small sample of data to make everything reproducible.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik details added! thanks!

Comment: There appear to be differences in plot size. The question is, does ggvis map circle size, or does it map radius of the plot? Can you provide the data and code in an easy to copy/paste manner? The shiny application isn't really necessary to demonstrate what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

`scale_numeric` function controls the max and min sizes

```
mtcars  %>% 
   ggvis(~wt,~mpg,size=~mpg) %>% 
   scale_numeric('size',domain = c(10,40),range=c(100,1000)) %>%
   layer_points()
```

[image]

`range` sets the minimum and maximum sizes, `domain` sets the range of data. You don't need that by default

A few notes on your reproducible example: I as a person trying to help, cannot run your code and tinker with it because 1. It is provided as half of a shiny application (only server code) and 2. data isn't easily accessible. Your problem was your inability to set the data ranges. It is easier for third parties to help you if they can replicate your problem in its most minimal form